# Sorting filesets numerically in Ant

Tags: sorting, ant

I have a folder structure like this:

```
wsdl/v1,----,v11
```

I need to copy all of its files to a new folder called "latestVersion" and I need to maintain the copying order from v1 to v11. So to do that, I need to sort the directories by name while copying. My code is like this:

```
<copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latestVersion" flatten="true" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
    <sort>
        <fileset dir="../../sdk/etc/wsdl">
            <include name="**/*.wsdl"/>
        </fileset>
    </sort>
</copy>
```

I would like the copying to start from v1 and end in v11. However, it copies like this:

```
v1,v10,v11,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9
```

How, instead, do I get Ant to copy like:

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript embedded in an Ant script to numerically sort the directory names.

Then, you can use [`<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) from the third-party [Ant-Contrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to copy from the sorted directories one at a time:

```
<dirset id="wsdl.dirs" dir="../../sdk/etc/wsdl" includes="v*"/>
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    var dirSet = project.getReference( "wsdl.dirs" );
    var ds = dirSet.getDirectoryScanner( project );
    var includes = ds.getIncludedDirectories();
    var versions = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < includes.length; i++ ) {
        var dirname = includes[i]
        // chop off the "v" from the front
        var dirVersion = dirname.substr(1);
        versions.push( dirVersion );
    }
    versionsSorted = versions.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    // the "list" of <for> takes a comma-delimited string
    project.setProperty( "versions", versionsSorted.join( ',' ) );
]]>
</script>
<echo>sorted versions: ${versions}</echo>

<for list="${versions}" param="version">
    <sequential>
        <copy todir="${srcdist.layout.dir}/etc/wsdl/latestVersion">
            <fileset dir="../../sdk/etc/wsdl/v@{version}" includes="**/*.wsdl"/>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ant is sorting correctly, since `v10` comes before `v2` lexicographically (the sorting comparator compares characters one by one).

In order to have `v2` before `v11` you have to write a custom comparator (the list of built-in comparators in the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort) is not enough). In other words, you have to write a class that implements the `org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators.ResourceComparator` class, add your class to the classpath and declare it as a typedef in your Ant script:

```
<typedef name="my_custom_sort" classname="com.example.MyCustomResourceComparator" />
```